# Content Approval Set to No In SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development

I want to set content approval "no" in sharepoint list in version setting programmatically at the time of list creation. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: How are you creating it today? C#, javascript, GUI?

Comment: For any folks new to SharePoint that see this question, please note that when creating in the user interface, the default setting for Content Approval is "No."

Answer (score 0):

Read this

list_properties

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list_properties%28v=office.15%29.aspx

list.enablemoderation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.enablemoderation%28v=office.15%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

Set content approval to *No* programmatically :

```
SPList list = web.Lists["myList"];
list.EnableModeration = false;
```

Ref: [List.EnableModeration property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.enablemoderation.aspx)